# build java project with two scripts

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote two scripts in ruby. I use netbeans, and I would like to automatically run this scripts whenever I build a Java project in Netbeans. How can I do this?

Comment: @Lazarus - Java isn't a scripting language and you haven't indicated how your 'Java' scripts would be run as part of the build process.

Comment: @bstick12: What luck you were around to highlight that for me. Mind you, I never said to write scripts in 'Java' (whatever 'Java' is and however it's different from Java). I actually say to "write in Java". As for executing other code during a build process, we'd be more than a little hampered if we could only run scripts. Have you never used Java for CLI programming?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the documentation here - http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html

The Customizing the Build Script Section would be where you would have your Ruby scripts executed from.

For example to run a ruby script after compilation

```
<target name="-post-compile">
  <exec executable="/path/to/ruby">
    <arg value="/path/to/ruby/script"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Consider demonstrating how to do that specifically.